# Excel how to add spacing between numbers and letters

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have an order number "CP1045" in excel which I need to put spaces between each letter and number. Example  : C P 1 0 4 5

Comment: Spacing (make distance between chars more wide) or spaces (add space chars)?

Comment: distance between chars more wide

Comment: Excel is not a desktop publishing application. If you need fancy letter spacing, use InDesign or something similar.

Comment: Excel have no such font formatting. Use Word... Alternatively you may use custom font.

Comment: OK what about separating each character to individual cell

Comment: Like C to A1, P to A2, 1 to A3etcetc

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not have any functionality to do what you describe. Maybe you can find a font that uses large gaps between letters, but this is nothing that Excel can do out of the box.

Don't shoot the messenger.